# authenticate user with devise rails 3 in any controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i use rails 3 and devise plugin version 1.1.2. How i can authenticate user through email and password in any controllers?

Comment: Try their Sample apps here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications

Answer (score 4):

Solved. There is public method sign_in @user, where @user is your user object with attr, such as password and email for example

Comment: Hi, `sign_in` is the method you would use during testing, to automatically sign in a user. If that was your question, then that was not clear. Normally you would add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to make sure a controller cannot be reached unless a user is logged in, and will redirect to login-screen otherwise.